# Set 404 redirect before 301 with IIS config file

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I got a website where is working 301 redirect from url with "/" in the end to the same link without "/".
e.g. from **[www.website.com/test/](http://www.website.com/test/)** to **[www.website.com/test](http://www.website.com/test)**
it seems that this part of config do this

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/$"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

and now I need to make 404 redirect from urls like **[www.website.com/test123/](http://www.website.com/test123/)** when "/test123/" doesn't exist before it redirects to **[www.website.com/test123](http://www.website.com/test123)**

I have this section in config

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
  <clear/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/PageNotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

but it doesn't help.

[image: this is how it looks now]
Is it possible to do 404 before it makes 301 redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, the execution of redirection is before the error page, but you can consider using the url redirect rule to redirect it to a custom error page when there is a mismatch.

Comment: Yeah, I have a uniqe page for 404 error. but I need get rid of 301 before 404. Sad that its impossible.. I dont know why CEO guys asked me about this. They said its bad do do 301 before 404... I cant get it )